# Specify maintainer of Linux kernel Debian package

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

My team currently builds custom Linux kernels.  I've noticed however that when we do an `apt-cache show linux-image-4.19.160-widget` the maintainer is the team member that built it (i.e. Maintainer: John Doe <john.doe@widgetco.com>).  I want that field to reflect the team rather than the member that built the kernel (i.e. Widget Team <team@widgetco.com>).  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  We currently build the kernel using the following command:

```
make -C $(KERNEL_ROOT_SRC_DIR) bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-widget
```

Comment: Find the variable containing that data. My guess is that it is a git variable (git user or some such thing): try changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The “Maintainer” entry, and the `debian/changelog` entry, can be set by defining the `DEBEMAIL` or `EMAIL` environment variables:

```
DEBEMAIL="Widget Team <team@widgetco.com>" make bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-widget
```

The variable needs to be set in the environment, not as a make command-line variable.